# ReactJS: Two different styles for one component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that I use twice in the same code, it looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'Base/Grid/Container';
import styles from './index.css';

const Columns = props => <Container {...props} className={styles.root} block/>;
export default Columns;
```

How can i, when importing, apply another style class to the second used `Columns`?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can put a ternary condition like this: `className={ x == 1 ? styles.root : style.otherClassName}`. Here `x == 1` is your condition.

Comment: jst give styles from where you are using this component. and set it as a default style, so if you will not get the style from parent component, it will take this `styles.root` as default.

Comment: Do you want to apply another styles together with the one already there? Or is it going to be different style, based on some condition?

Comment: Solution suggested by Arpit is correct, or you can also go for conditional rendering https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Darn, I read "an other" instead of "another"

Comment: Also you can simply pass the "classname" from the other component as a prop and here `const {classname, ...rest} = props ;` then  `<Container className={classname} block {...rest} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define another style beside of your `styles.root` that is passed from the props. Like below:

```
const Columns = props => <Container {...props} className={[styles.root,props.newStyles]} block/>;
```

So when you make a `Columns` component you can pass the specific styles. For example:

```
<Columns newStyles={{color: 'red'}} />
```

So you can customize the style for each component which you use.

or if you don't want to use the `root style` you can make it conditional that if there the `newStyle` was passed use it. If not just use the `styles.root`. And the code would be like this:

```
Columns = props => <Container {...props} className={props.newStyle || styles.root} block/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution is to use react composition. Declare the "base" component in one file, and then export in two different files with two different names the styled one.

```js
// BaseComponent.jsx
export default Column = () => <div>Column</div>;

// RedColumn.jsx
import Column from './Column';

const RedColumn = () => <Column style={{color: "red"}} />;

export default RedColumn;

// BlueColumn.jsx
import Column from './Column';

const BlueColumn = () => <Column style={{color: "blue"}} />;

export default BlueColumn;
```